# How to start Openssh server after install in WSL?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying run the command ssh localhost but receive the error

ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

WhenI try to check the status of the SSH Server with the command sudo service ssh status I receive the error

- sshd is not running

I installed the SSH Client with sudo apt-get install openssh-client and the SSH Server with sudo apt-get install openssh-server ii. What else could the issue be thank you.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you that fixed it the sshd is now running.

Comment: I have converted my comment to an answer. Please accept the answer below by clicking on the gray check mark ✔next to it and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that the answer is correct and help others with the same problem. You can also up-vote my answer to show your appreciation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## WSL does not automatically start `sshd`

Try removing the ssh server with:

```
sudo apt remove openssh-server
```

And then install it again with:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Then check the server status to see if it is running. If not, try:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

to start the server. See more [here](https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

wsl 2 now supports crontab
Add this to your crontab

```
@reboot sudo service ssh start
```